# Auto focus Kendo textarea on selecting a value from dropdown

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo window where I have a dropdown with list of items. On changing the value of dropdown, the cursor should automatically focus on kendo textarea. But its not happening. Can someone please help me to achieve this.

```
 $('#Teamplate').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: dataPost,
        success: function (data) {
         //do some operations  
        },
        complete: function(){
           $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").focus();
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `complete` callback is being fired?  Have you tried moving it to the `success` callback?

Comment: Hi mmillican, yes, complete callback is getting fired. Earlier I have tried by keeping in success callback.. as it will be asynchronous I have moved it to complete callback. Even when it was in success callback, it didn't work as expected.

Comment: `$("#editor").data("kendoEditor").focus()` should work. Can you post the complete view source code?